# Why does Windows Server 2012 R2 recognize a local administrator over the network for some purposes but not others?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2, workgroup, security

I have researched this at length, but cannot find a solution to the specific issue I'm getting. Evidently there are a number of similar issues that regularly cause problems for people trying to connect or issue remote commands to a Windows server, but none of the solutions I've found help in this case.

Scenario (no domain involved):

- UserA has a workgroup account on WorkstationA (Win7 Ultimate).
- UserA has a workgroup account on ServerA (2012 R2).
- UserA is in the Administrators group on both machines.

With this setup, UserA is able to remote desktop to the server and carry out administrative tasks.

But if UserA tries to shut down ServerA from a WorkstationA command prompt, even from an administrator command prompt, access is denied:

```
shutdown /m \\ServerA /t 0 /s
ServerA: Access is denied.(5)
```

Similarly, direct access is denied to the server's filesystem using Windows Explorer, which triggers a username/password dialog.

And here's the thing:

- All  this used to work, on Server 2008 and 2008R2
- If UserA logs on to WorkstationA as the user called Administrator (instead of the UserA account which is in the Administrators group on both machines), it all works.

Comment: Why aren't you using a domain anyways?

Comment: Looks like UAC is getting in the way...

Answer (score 1):

I've found the cause, and it's none other than our dear friend UAC.

I stumbled on this by experimentation, after recalling that (depending on settings) UAC will prompt members of the Administrators group for privilege elevation, while the built-in Administrator gets automatic elevation without prompting. This led me to wonder if it was an issue with prompting a remote user.

I found that with UAC disabled, everything started to work as expected.

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be any setting that allows these things to work with UAC enabled. I tried all the UAC-related policy settings (such as "elevate administrators without prompting") in case they might solve my issue as a side-effect, but found no joy there.

I've just booted up a 2008R2 server to double-check what I said in the question about earlier versions, and it is indeed the case that with UAC enabled, it allows the access in question from the same UserA on WorkstationA.

So it seems this behaviour has changed in 2012 or as a result of an update.

So I have an answer, but no solution yet. I do not intend to mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check what groups the user administrator is included in. I've had this problem with our servers, and although there was no domain when we were playing around with it, the domain administrator group was what was causing the problem... I had to add the user to the domain admin group before I could use remote commands.

So just check the security groups :) I imagine your problem is there somewhere :D

I hope this helps

Comment: Sadly no, user Administrator is in only the Administrators group on both machines involved.

Comment: Agh, that sucks, erm, okay, so have you tried explicitly enabling access to the shared file system to userA? (On the server)

Comment: it's UAC--see my answer (no solution yet though).

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable the Built-In Administrator account (and reboot to apply changes):

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

You can read more about it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766343(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: The built-in Administrator is already working, as I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

To disable UAC remote restrictions, follow these steps: 
Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then press ENTER.
Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
If the LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy registry entry does not exist, follow these steps: 
On the Edit menu, point to
New, and then click DWORD Value.
Type LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy, and then press ENTER.
Right-click LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy, and then click Modify.
In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.
Exit Registry Editor.